# Can you plot standard graphs with aniamtions in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I am trying to make a grid of graphs and maps but would like them to be animated. Currently, the static version looks like the image below:

[image: Current output]

My hope is to animate the points on the map as well as the line graph, whilst the bar chart is static. Does anyone know how I would go about doing that? When I try to use the gganimate on the map but not the graphs it comes up with a warning. I can get them to animate on their own but not when they are in the grid form altogether. Perhaps I need to use the same time_frame in all of them but was hoping to have 2 separate animations and a static graph presented on the same page, so if anyone knows how to help that would be great!

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: You might want to check out this: https://github.com/thomasp85/gganimate/wiki/Animation-Composition